# Newbie get _id of returned where query

Tags: mongodb

Selecting specific item from returned query (newbie)

Using laravel with the https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#query-builder package so the php is a bit off the norm for MongoDB terminology

I query the database like so:

```
$role_id = Role::where('name', 'Admin')->get();
```

How do I access the '_id' of the returned query?

I would like to grab the '_id' in a variable

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns `Illuminate\Support\Collection` object. That means you are getting an array of return items. So, in your case, you should iterate `$role_id` to loop through the items and get `_id`. Like this -

`foreach ($rid as $role_id) {
    echo $rid->_id;
}`

Comment: Thanks for that,     foreach ($role_id as $rid) {
        echo $rid->_id;
    } prints out the value, then I try $myval = $rid[0] but $myval comes out as NULL, I thought that was how you referenced an array?